# Preferences/General - How do I get it to save in Lion?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I don't want my apps to open previous windows.  When I go into Prefs/General and unclick "Restore windows when quitting...," and close preferences, it doesn't save it.  When I re-open Prefs/General, it's checked again.

I can't change the preferences in anything.  Safari keeps opening the same last two windows and when I go into Safari Preferences and change "New tabs open with:" to 'Home Page'; once I close and open up again, it's back to 'Top Sites.'

Comment: This sounds like a bug that Apple would need to fix, however, it could also be a permissions problem. Can you open Console.app, reproduce this, and report any error messages that appear in Console?

Comment: bneely...sorry that's out of my league.  I can open Console.app (why are there two?) but after that I'm staring at a box of rocks.  This is a new MacBook Air and I have been having some permissions problems that were caused when the Apple Store created a "test" account to transfer files. Might be time for another one-to-one visit. Thanks!

Comment: I would check ~/Library/ and ~/Library/Preference's permissions so you can read and write, because that's where all the preferences are stored.

Answer (score 1):

Need to reset permissions? Try the following:

1. Turn off computer
2. Reboot Mac into Recovery (press and hold Command+R when you hear the chimes until a screen loads)
3. Select "Disk Utility"
   [image]
4. Select your "Macintosh HD" volume on the left and press "Repair Disk Permissions"
   [image]
5. Once that has finished, reboot your computer